# Is it necessary to create pages with the recent changes to the Facebook like button?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I was reading over the [changes to the Facebook Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/) that are scheduled to take place in November 2012, and I'm a bit confused (and hoping someone has an answer).

I understand that the REST endpoints are being removed in favour of regular pages, but here's where I'm confused.

Previously, if I did the following...

- Create a page
- Add the correct OpenGraph metatags to the page
- 'Like' the page

... Then an OpenGraph object would be created *automatically* (and could be verified by visiting http://graph.facebook.com/?id=my_url). If I published to that OpenGraph object, people would receive updates.

However, with the changes, if I understand them correctly, the OpenGraph object is no longer created? Or it is created, but I still need to create a Facebook page to administer and send messages?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, with the changes, if I understand them correctly, the OpenGraph object is no longer created?

That phrasing is a little besides the point.

*You* create the Open Graph object, by setting up a page with appropriate OG meta tags.

And Facebook will count likes for this URL, like for every other URL.

> Or it is created, but I still need to create a Facebook page to administer and send messages?

No admin pages will be created automatically any more; although you can convert *existing* ones to normal public Facebook pages. But then you have to point the like button to the URL of that new Facebook page instead of your OG URL to be able to publish updates to your fans. (So this will behave basically like a normal Facebook page that was set up to be one in the first place; only this step allows you to “migrate” your existing likers for your OG URL to that page, so you don’t need to have a “fresh start” with your Facebook page.)

The document further describes, what to do if you still need the ability to publish updates to the users liking your OG URL – by providing `fb:app_id` and `fb:admins` meta tags:

> *“This will ensure that the Like Button admin link still appears on the given Open Graph page. The admin page for a given Like Button is also accessible to administrators from https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/pages”*

**But publishing updates this way will only work until the Like Button admin page is fully deprecated.** From then on, you will *have* to use a Facebook page, if you want to be able to publish updates to the users who liked your page.

Comment: So, just to clarify, after the migration occurs, if I had a site with 1000 products, and I wanted to communicate via any single one, I would need to create 1000 pages manually?

Comment: Also to clarify, I would need to point the Facebook like button at the fan page instead of the Open Graph URL (the canonical URL of the page)?